# How to use ParseServerOptions

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I am using Parse Server v2.8.2. I am trying to use src/Options/index.js to rebuild src/Options/Definitions.js using the following command

`$ node resources/buildConfigDefinitions.js`

But when I execute this command, nothing seems to happen. Besides when I run

`parse-server --appId=def --masterKey=abc - databaseURI=mongodb://localhost/test`

I can't get the configuration I'm setting in the

> src/Options/index.js file.

Does anyone know how this works and how to actually get the configuration in the index.js file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forget the rebuild. You can combine .env settings AND specify a config file both on the cmdLine, letting the default priorities establish themselves for actual , runtime config.properties...

since you are with node...

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "node ./bin/parse-server -- lib/conf.json",
```

.env OR cli settings ...

```
VERBOSE=1
PORT=1337
PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=06rc7
PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=wwTQ
PARSE_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:1337/parse
PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:1337/parse
PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://parse:adm@931.mb.com:13931/ntst
FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY=../lib/fbidentity.json
FIREBASE_
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKYA
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=Marw9
S3_BUCKET=y
S3_REGION=
```

conf.json ...

```
{
"databaseURI": "",
"appId": "",
"masterKey": "",
"serverURL": "",
"verifyUserEmails": true,
"publicServerURL": "",
"appName": "Yayatv App",
"filesAdapter": {
    "module": "@parse/s3-files-adapter",
    "options": {
      "bucket": "",
      "region": ""
    }
},
"emailAdapter": {
  "module": "@parse/simple-mailgun-adapter",
  "options": {
    "fromAddress": "no-reply@mg.tv.tv",
    "domain": "mg.yv.tv",
    "apiKey": "key-478"
  }
},
"auth" : {
   "firebase" : {
       "module" : "parse-server-firebase-auth-adapter"
   }
}
}
```